# Sharing code repositories between Mac Host and Vm Fusion Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macos, virtual-machine, code-sharing

I keep a shared folder with all the my git repositories on mac.
I access it also with a Windows 7 Virtual Machine (Vmware Fusion) for doing Visual Studio Mvc projects.

Compared to having a duplicate of the repository folder directly inside the Windows VM the complilation and debugging is much slower, there are limitations with IIS, and the VM size grows a lot.

Are there better ways to speed up the process?

Comment: Have you looked into mirrored folders? http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014127